# Date.toString() adds an hour around epoch in London

Tags: java, date

How can I get Date.toString() to produce an output that SimpleDateFormat can parse correctly for Dates around 1 Jan 1970 (I assume this applies to winter of 1968 and 1969 as well)

If I run the following,

```
System.out.println(TimeZone.getDefault());
Date date = new Date(0);
SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("EEE MMM dd HH:mm:ss zzz yyyy");
Date date2 = sdf.parse(date.toString());
System.out.println("date: " + date);
System.out.println("date2: " + date2);
Date date3 = sdf.parse(date2.toString());
System.out.println("date3: " + date3);
```

This prints

```
sun.util.calendar.ZoneInfo[id="Europe/London",offset=0,dstSavings=3600000,useDaylight=true,transitions=242,lastRule=java.util.SimpleTimeZone[id=Europe/London,offset=0,dstSavings=3600000,useDaylight=true,startYear=0,startMode=2,startMonth=2,startDay=-1,startDayOfWeek=1,startTime=3600000,startTimeMode=2,endMode=2,endMonth=9,endDay=-1,endDayOfWeek=1,endTime=3600000,endTimeMode=2]]
date: Thu Jan 01 01:00:00 GMT 1970
date2: Thu Jan 01 02:00:00 GMT 1970
date3: Thu Jan 01 03:00:00 GMT 1970
```

The problem is that London was in BST on 1 Jan 1970. So the correct date should be either

```
date: Thu Jan 01 01:00:00 BST 1970
```

or

```
date: Thu Jan 01 00:00:00 GMT 1970
```

but it seems a confusion of the two.

And while I would love to not support java.util.Date, it's not an option for me.

Comment: For those of us outside of the UK, I was able to duplicate this by including `TimeZone.setDefault(TimeZone.getTimeZone("Europe/London"));` before the above code.

Comment: @AndyTurner Question added, thank you.

Comment: From what I can tell, BST starts in March and ends in September. Am I misinterpreting the question?

Comment: @Compass Correct, it usually does, I see you answered your own question below. ;)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

## tl;dr

Your **input is invalid** as `BST` (British Summer Time) was not in effect during the winter.

`BST` cannot be reliably parsed, as it is a non-standard non-unique pseudo-zone.

There is no need to mess around with `SimpleDateFormat`. Let the modern  *java.time* classes do the heavy lifting.

> And while I would love to not support [`java.util.Date`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Date.html), it's not an option for me.

At the edges of your code, **convert to-from the legacy and modern** classes.

```
// Convert from legacy to modern.
Instant instant = myJavaUtilDate.toInstant() ;

// Convert from modern to legacy.
java.util.Date myJavaUtilDate = Date.from( instant ) ;
```

## No `BST` in winter

Apparently the “B” in your `BST` is meant to be British. But `BST` in that context means [*British Summer Time*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/British_Summer_Time). This means [Daylight Saving Time (DST)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Daylight_saving_time) which is engaged in the summer time, not the winter. So **your input string of a January date combined with `BST` is nonsensical**.

### Double-Summertime

There is a further complication to your example of a moment in 1970 with a British time zone.

The practice of DST in Britain using an offset of one hour ahead of UTC (+01:00) in summer, and an offset of zero (+00:00) in the winter for Standard Time is *current* practice. That has not always been the case.

Back in 1970, Britain was [trialling a “double-summertime”](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/British_Summer_Time#Debates_on_reform). In that experiment of 1968-1971, winter time was *one* hour ahead of UTC rather than zero, and summer time was *two* hours ahead of UTC instead of the one hour used nowadays. This put British time more in common with continental Europe and was hoped to reduce accidents.

So if we adjust a moment in January of 1970, we expect to jump to one hour ahead for time zone `Europe/London`. Whereas a moment in January of 2019, we expect no jump, the time-of-day in Britain will be the same as UTC (an offset-from-UTC of zero hours-minutes-seconds).

## Avoid pseudo-zones

Avoid these 2-4 character pseudo-zones such as `BST`. They are not standardized. They are not even unique! So `BST` can be interpreted to be the time zone [`Pacific/Bougainville`](https://time.is/Bougainville) just as well as `British Summer Time`.

Specify a [proper time zone name](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_tz_zones_by_name) in the format of `Continent/Region`, such as `America/Montreal`, `Africa/Casablanca`, or `Pacific/Auckland`. Never use the 2-4 letter abbreviation such as `BST` or `EST` or `IST` as they are *not* true time zones, not standardized, and not even unique(!).

## Convert

You can convert between the legacy and modern date-time classes easily. New conversion methods have been added to the old classes. Look for `from`, `to`, and `valueOf` methods, per [the naming conventions](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/overview/naming.html).

- [`java.util.Date`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Date.html) ⇄ `java.time.Instant`
- `java.util.GregorianCalendar` ⇄ `java.time.ZonedDateTime`
- [`java.sql.Date`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Date.html) ⇄ `java.time.LocalDate`
- `java.sql.Timestamp` ⇄ `java.time.Instant`

## Converting

Your input string of 00:00 on January 1, 1970 happens to be the [epoch reference date](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Epoch_(reference_date)) used by both the legacy and modern date-time classes. We have a constant for that value.

```
Instant epoch = Instant.EPOCH ;
```

> instant.toString(): 1970-01-01T00:00:00Z

See that same moment through your time zone of `Europe/London`.

```
ZoneId z = ZoneId.of( "Europe/London" ) ;
ZonedDateTime zdt = epoch.atZone( z ) ;
```

> zdt.toString(): 1970-01-01T01:00+01:00[Europe/London]

Notice that above-mentioned *Double-Summertime* experiment in effect then. If we try the same code for 2019, we get an [offset-from-UTC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTC_offset) of zero.

```
ZonedDateTime zdt2019 = 
    Instant
    .parse( "2019-01-01T00:00Z" )
    .atZone( ZoneId.of( "Europe/London" ) )
;
```

> zdt2019.toString(): 2019-01-01T00:00Z[Europe/London]

To convert to a `java.util.Date`, we need an `java.time.Instant` object. An `Instant` represents a moment in UTC. We can extract an `Instant` from our `ZonedDateTime` object, effectively adjusting from a zone to UTC. Same moment, different wall-clock time.

```
Instant instant = zdt.toInstant():
```

We should now be back where we started, at the epoch reference date of 1970-01-01T00:00:00Z.

> instant.toString(): 1970-01-01T00:00:00Z

To get the `java.util.Date` object you may need to interoperate with old code not yet updated to *java.time* classes, use the new [`Date.from`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Date.html#from(java.time.Instant)) method added to the old class.

```
java.util.Date d = Date.from( instant ) ; // Same moment, but with possible data-loss as nanoseconds are truncated to milliseconds.
```

> d.toString(): Thu Jan 01 00:00:00 GMT 1970

By the way, be aware of possible data-loss when converting from `Instant` to [`Date`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Date.html). The modern classes have a resolution of [nanoseconds](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nanosecond) while the legacy classes use [milliseconds](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Millisecond). So part of your fractional second may be truncated.

See all the code above [run live at IdeOne.com](https://ideone.com/UlX4ac).

To convert the other direction, use the [`Date::toInstant`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Date.html#toInstant()) method.

```
Instant instant = d.toInstant() ;
```

## ISO 8601

Avoid using text in custom formats for exchanging date-time values. When serializing date-time values as human-readable text, use only the standard [ISO 8601](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601) formats. The *java.time* classes use these formats by default.

Those strings you were experimenting with parsing are a *terrible* format and should never be used for data-exchange.

---

## About *java.time*

The [*java.time*](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) framework is built into Java 8 and later. These classes supplant the troublesome old [legacy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legacy_system) date-time classes such as [`java.util.Date`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/Date.html), [`Calendar`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html), & [`SimpleDateFormat`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html).

The [*Joda-Time*](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/) project, now in [maintenance mode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maintenance_mode), advises migration to the [java.time](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) classes.

To learn more, see the [*Oracle Tutorial*](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/TOC.html). And search Stack Overflow for many examples and explanations. Specification is [JSR 310](https://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=310).

You may exchange *java.time* objects directly with your database. Use a [JDBC driver](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JDBC_driver) compliant with [JDBC 4.2](http://openjdk.java.net/jeps/170) or later. No need for strings, no need for `java.sql.*` classes.

Where to obtain the java.time classes?

- [**Java SE 8**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_8), [**Java SE 9**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_9), [**Java SE 10**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_10), [**Java SE 11**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_11), and later  - Part of the standard Java API with a bundled implementation.
- Java 9 adds some minor features and fixes.
- [**Java SE 6**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_6) and [**Java SE 7**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_7)
- Most of the *java.time* functionality is back-ported to Java 6 & 7 in [***ThreeTen-Backport***](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/).
- [**Android**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Android_(operating_system))
- Later versions of Android bundle implementations of the *java.time* classes.
- For earlier Android (<26), the [***ThreeTenABP***](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ThreeTenABP) project adapts [***ThreeTen-Backport***](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/) (mentioned above). See [*How to use ThreeTenABP…*](http://stackoverflow.com/q/38922754/642706).

The [**ThreeTen-Extra**](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/) project extends java.time with additional classes. This project is a proving ground for possible future additions to java.time. You may find some useful classes here such as [`Interval`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/Interval.html), [`YearWeek`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/YearWeek.html), [`YearQuarter`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/YearQuarter.html), and [more](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/index.html).

Answer (score 4):

I may cite https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-6609362?jql=text%20~%20%22epoch%20gmt%22:

> Please use Z to format and parse historical time zone offset changes
>   to avoid confusions with historical time zone name changes.
>
> ````
> public class Test {
>     public static void main(String[] args) throws ParseException {
>         TimeZone.setDefault(TimeZone.getTimeZone("Europe/London"));
>         SimpleDateFormat f = new SimpleDateFormat("EEE MMM dd HH:mm:ss Z yyyy");
>         Date d = new Date(0);
>         for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
>             String s = f.format(d);
>             System.out.println(s);
>             d = f.parse(s);
>         }
>     } } ```
> ````

Comment: Thank you. Is there any way to get Date.toString() to behave? I tried overriding the default timezone.

Comment: None that I am aware of. This seems to be one of many issues with java.util.Date. There is a reason for java.time.*.

Answer (score 2):

This is why I hate the Date Library.

As implied, BST should be used during the summer, and the calendar defines it as such.

```
sun.util.calendar.ZoneInfo[id="Europe/London",offset=0,dstSavings=3600000,useDaylight=true,transitions=242,lastRule=java.util.SimpleTimeZone[id=Europe/London,offset=0,dstSavings=3600000,useDaylight=true,startYear=0,startMode=2,startMonth=2,startDay=-1,startDayOfWeek=1,startTime=3600000,startTimeMode=2,endMode=2,endMonth=9,endDay=-1,endDayOfWeek=1,endTime=3600000,endTimeMode=2]]
```

Except, for, TIL of [The adventures of year-round British Summer Time!](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/British_Summer_Time)

> A further inquiry during 1966–67 led the government of Harold Wilson to introduce the British Standard Time experiment, **with Britain remaining on GMT+1 throughout the year.** This took place between **27 October 1968 and 31 October 1971,** when there was a reversion to the previous arrangement.

If you test dates around this period you will find the dates drifting off by an hour each parse, up to the switchover points.

The time code for Europe/London is GMT, with daylight savings using BST.

The `toString` method of Date "normalizes" the output by removing daylight savings time to pick what time zone to print. The options are `GMT` and `BST`. The Europe/London time of 01:00:00 printed as 01:00:00 **GMT** even though it is operating on GMT+1 time. So in other words, `date.toString()`does not work properly for this swath of time around the epoch because it uses GMT as a time zone for a time zone that is ostensibly not GMT/CET. The *time* itself is correct, but *not the time zone*.

The "simplest" solution I can come up with is relatively nasty from a sanity checkpoint, but can probably be made more elegant.

```
private static final Date experimentEnd = new Date(1971-1900, 11-1, 11);
private static final Date experimentStart = (new Date(1968-1900, 10-1, 26));

private static boolean bstExperimentTime(Date date) {
    return date.after(experimentStart) && date.before(experimentEnd);
}

public static String forDateParsing(Date date) {
    if(bstExperimentTime(date))
        return date.toString().replace("GMT", "CET");
    return date.toString();
}

public static String forDatePrinting(Date date) {
     if(bstExperimentTime(date))
        return date.toString().replace("GMT", "BST");
    return date.toString();
}
```

Any date you need to *parse* with default "Europe/London" time zone needs to be passed through the parse formatter to convert GMT -> CET, which is the correct GMT+1.

Any date you need to *print* with default "Europe/London" time zone needs to be passed through the parse formatter to convert GMT -> BST, which is the correct display.